# multiplying a case statement mysql

Tags: mysql, select, case

I'm trying to use a case statement to get the gpa of a student. When I use the case statement I only get 0 as the solution when multiplying the credits with the actual grade. I'm really confused on what I'm doing wrong.

```
select *, sum(c.credits * grade), sum(c.credits),
CASE grade
WHEN 'A' THEN 4.0 
WHEN 'A-' THEN 3.67 
WHEN 'B+' THEN 3.33
WHEN 'B' THEN 3
WHEN 'B-' THEN 2.67
WHEN 'C+' THEN 2.33
WHEN 'C' THEN 2
WHEN 'C-' THEN 1.67
WHEN 'D+' THEN 1.33
WHEN 'D' THEN 1
WHEN 'D-' THEN 0.67
ELSE 0 
END
from takes t join course c on t.course_id = c.course_id
group by t.ID;
```

I shows a column of `CASE grade` which contains the correct gpa for the letter grade that someone gets. Do I need to do a subquery to use the `CASE grade` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to multiple a number (credits) with a string (grade) that is why you are getting zero as result, try changing your query to:

```
SELECT
  t.ID,
  sum(
    c.credits * (
      CASE grade
        WHEN 'A' THEN 4.0 
        WHEN 'A-' THEN 3.67 
        WHEN 'B+' THEN 3.33
        WHEN 'B' THEN 3
        WHEN 'B-' THEN 2.67
        WHEN 'C+' THEN 2.33
        WHEN 'C' THEN 2
        WHEN 'C-' THEN 1.67
        WHEN 'D+' THEN 1.33
        WHEN 'D' THEN 1
        WHEN 'D-' THEN 0.67
        ELSE 0 
      END
    )
  ),
  sum(c.credits)
FROM
  takes t
INNER JOIN course c ON
  t.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY 
  t.ID;
```

Comment: That makes sense. Trying to multiply a string with a number. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated! Will accept the answer when I can